# Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' faliled

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

The below code I have in 2 other files works fine but for some reason i am getting this SaveAs of ojbect error when it runs. What is even stranger is if i debug and just hit run again it completes with no error.

```
Sub saveWorksheet()

Set report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
sb_Copy_Save_Worksheet_As_Workbook

End Sub


Sub sb_Copy_Save_Worksheet_As_Workbook()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.Sheets(1).Name = Day(Now) & "-" & MonthName(Month(Now), True) & "-" & 
Year(Now) & " " & getTime
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete

wb.SaveAs "\\Naeast.ad.jpmorganchase.com\amerawm$\AM\NAAMSHARE13\AM 
Oversight and control\DE Program Team\User Tools\14. Daily 
Trackers\Compliance Check Archive\" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & "-" 
& Year(Date) & "-" & "New_Compliance_Check.xlsx"
wb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Function getTime()

If Len(Time) = 10 Then
    getTime = Left(Time, 1) & "." & Mid(Time, 3, 2)
Else
    getTime = Left(Time, 2) & "." & Mid(Time, 4, 2)
End If

End Function
```

The debug line that is highlighted is:

```
wb.SaveAs "\\Naeast.ad.jpmorganchase.com\amerawm$\AM\NAAMSHARE13\AM Oversight and control\DE Program Team\User Tools\14. Daily Trackers\Compliance Check Archive\" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) & "-" & "New_Compliance_Check.xlsx"
```

EDIT: i updated the code to this based on your suggestion but same issue.

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
wb.Activate
wb.SaveAs "\\Naeast.ad.jpmorganchase.com\amerawm$\AM\NAAMSHARE13\AM 
Oversight and control\DE Program Team\User Tools\14. Daily 
Trackers\Compliance Check Archive\" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & "-" & 
Year(Date) & "-" & "New_Compliance_Check.xlsx"
wb.Close
```

Comment: One quick thing to do is to leave the DisplayAlerts on and see if an alert appears. In particular, there may be an alert if the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I've had situations like this before where Excel seems to get confused about which workbook I'm referring to. Try `wb.Activate` before `wb.SaveAs`

Also (not sure if this is applicable for you) but when saving to Sharepoint I've had to reverse all the `\` to `/` in the file path at times.